# Spark - Why is it necessary to collect() to the driver node before printing an RDD? Can it not be done in parallel?

Tags: java, apache-spark, parallel-processing, rdd

I was reading about how to print RDDs in Spark (I'm using Java), and it seems like most people just `collect()` (if the RDD is small enough) and use forall(println), or something like that. Is it not possible to print in parallel? Why do we have to collect the data onto the driver node in order to print?

I was thinking maybe it's because we can't use System.out in parallel, but I feel like that's not it. And furthermore, I'm not quite sure how one would even distribute the data and print parallelly, in terms of code. One approach I was thinking of was to do a mappartitions that doesn't do anything useful in terms of mapping, but it iterates through the partition and prints its contents.

Comment: It's about where you want to see the output. You can print on the workers, but that would leave the output on the workers (possibly in log files). But you typically want to see the output on the driver machine.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. If I wanted to do it distributively (so print in the worker logs), would it suffice to simply iterate through the RDD and print? I ask this because I'd like to do something that has a similar motivation; I'm trying to batch the elements of my RDD together within each of my worker nodes (so within partitions), wasn't too sure how to approach this.

Comment: Hi @ernest_k I was wondering if it is only about print because if so then how the output of select() can be seen in notebook, does `select()` calls `collect()` internally?

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal I believe notebooks print implicitly. And in that case, they do collect data to the driver. I'm surmising as I haven't used a notebook that prints data (and not the data frame or rdd object's to String). The point is `print` can run either on workers with local data or on driver with collected data depending on how/where it's called. And in the case of the notebook showing data after running select, the data is collected to the driver.

Comment: @ernest_k _`And in the case of the notebook showing data after running select, the data is collected to the driver.`_  so you mean `select()` does internally invoke `collect()` or is it just true for any other statement on worker?

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal If you mean `select()` as in `DataFrame.select()` or `DataFrame.selectExpr()` then no, that does not collect, it just returns a different data frame object. But if your notebook displays the data after you run `select`, then it does collect. And this is done by your notebook engine, not by Spark. And is that "select" the  SQL select or some other notebook-specific command? And which notebook engine are you referring to? (I've used Jupyter with Spark and of course it doesn't show data without explicitly collecting, but maybe you're using databricks or something else)

Comment: @ernest_k okay understood that it is collected by notebook engine, I am using databricks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the `collect()` method, you are returning all the results to the driver node. You will have a `List` instead of an `RDD`. Let's see an example **in local mode**. Suppose you have an RDD of Integer:

```
JavaRDD<Integer> rdd = sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));
```

If you call the `foreach` method (`stream().forEach()` in Java), the driver node will print all the elements in the `RDD` in the same order you created it.

```
rdd.collect().stream().forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

`Output: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`

If you want to print the results on each worker, you have to call the `foreach`method of the `RDD`. It will return nothing to the driver, and just will perform the computation you specify in the `foreach` method on each worker node.

```
rdd.foreach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

If you see the console (**local mode**), you will note that the `System.out.println(x)` has been executed in separated threads, since the output doesn't respect the original order:

`Output: 6, 3, 2, 1, 8, 9, 10, 4, 5, 7`

So if you execute it in distributed mode, each executor will print the result of the `System.out.println` operation on its log files.

You also mentioned the `mapPartitions` method. In your case, I don't find it more useful than using the `foreach` directly over the `RDD`. It just may helpful to control the workers workload.

```
 rdd.repartition(5).mapPartitions(x -> {
     while(x.hasNext()){
         Integer i = x.next();
         System.out.println(i);
     }
     return x;
 }).count(); // Count is just to force the execution of mapPartition (mapPartition is lazy and doesn't get executed until an action is called)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I see, thanks for the well thought out explanation, you answered the question. Semirelated question if that's okay, do you think using for each would still be useful for me in the case where I need to batch entries together into Lists (as a simplified example)? So using your example, if I wanted to change my JavaRDD<Integer> into a JavaRDD<List<Integer>> where each List<Integer> consists of 100 Integers?